# How to print a christmas tree in Java, by calling methods?

Tags: java

I neeed help with the following problem.
This program has three outputs: one triangle, and two christmas trees. I have been successful with printing the triangle, but I can't figure out how to get my tree work. Here is the link to the exercise 40: https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part1/week-2/

Please note, this is not my hoomework. I am learning how to code by myself, at home.

Here is the code:

```
public static void xmasTree(int height) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ ) {
        printWhitespaces(height - 1);
        printStars( i ); 

    }
 for( int j = 2; j <= height; j++ ){
            printWhitespaces ( height - j );
            printStars ( j - 1 ); 
        }

}
```

This must be the final output:

```
            *
           ***
          *****
         *******
        *********
       ***********
      *************
     ***************
    *****************
   *******************
           ***
           ***
```

But I get this:

```
            *
            **
            ***
            ****
            *****
            ******
            *******
            ********
            *********
            **********
           *
          **
         ***
        ****
       *****
      ******
     *******
    ********
   *********
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write down what you need to do.

Each line consist of spaces for indentation, and stars for the tree, so write down how many of each you need.

Since you'll be using a loop, e.g. counting from `0` to `height - 1`, write down the iterator value too

```
                      height = 10
         *            9 spaces,  1 stars, i = 0
        ***           8 spaces,  3 stars, i = 1
       *****          7 spaces,  5 stars, i = 2
      *******         6 spaces,  7 stars, i = 3
     *********        5 spaces,  9 stars, i = 4
    ***********       4 spaces, 11 stars, i = 5
   *************      3 spaces, 13 stars, i = 6
  ***************     2 spaces, 15 stars, i = 7
 *****************    1 spaces, 17 stars, i = 8
*******************   0 spaces, 19 stars, i = 9
        ***           8 spaces,  3 stars
        ***           8 spaces,  3 stars
```

Now see if you can discern the pattern:

```
spaces = height - 1 - i
stars = 2 * i + 1
```

For the trunk, you loop `2` times, use `height - 2` spaces, and `3` stars, unless of course the trunk needs to somehow size with the tree height, but you didn't specify any rules for that.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, get used to using 0 as the first value in your loops, not 1. It takes some getting used to but it'll feel natural after 5 or 6 years :-)

You've certainly got a logic problem there. Each line for the top part of the tree should start at `height - i -1` (not `height - 1`) and contain `i * 2 + 1` stars (not `i`).

Similar issue with the trunk but I'll leave that with you as an exercise (since that's the point!).

Comment: Or, you could increment `i` by `2` on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void xmasTree(int height) {

    // cone
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ ) {
        printWhitespaces(height - i);
        printStars( i );
        printStars( i-1 );
        System.out.println();
    }

    // trunk
    for(int i=1 ; i<=4; i++){
        printWhitespaces(height - height/4 -1);
        printStars(height/2);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Explanation:

For printing the cone:

`____h-1__*__h-1____`    // h-i. Here, the number of stars = 2i-1. The star at position i becomes the midpoint

`___h-1__***___h-1__`

`__h-2__*****__h-2__`

and so on

For the trunk (assuming width changes):

`__h/4__*****__h/4__`    // width of the trunk = h/2

`__h/4__*****__h/4__`

and so on.

But as stated in the other answers, better to start with 0 in loops:

```
public static void xmasTree(int height) {

    // cone
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
        printWhitespaces(height - i - 1);
        printStars( i+1 );
        printStars( i );
        System.out.println();
    }

    // trunk
    for(int i = 0 ; i<4; i++){
        printWhitespaces(height - height/4 -1);
        printStars(height/2);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```